# Wrong MYSQL Create Function syntax?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a function like this in MYSQL:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `submit`(title VARCHAR(45)) RETURNS INT
  BEGIN
    DECLARE articleId INT;
    INSERT INTO Articles (`Title`) VALUES (title);
    SET @articleId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    RETURN (articleId);
  END
$$ DELIMITER ;
```

No matter how I change it (including removing everything in the body and placing a "return 1;"  instead) I get:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '*DELIMITER $$ CREATE FUNCTION `submit`(title v*' at line 1

What am I missing?

I'm using MySQL 5.5

**EDIT**

Apparently, MySQL is ignoring the first statement (`DELIMITER $$`), failing on the first `;` it finds, right after `articleId INT` in the 4th line. I had to reduce the code to the shortest form possible to make sure that's the case.

So I guess my question now is - Why is the `DELIMITER` keyword ignored?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky, I did override the `;` as the question you're referring to suggests. As you can see (if you have bothered to actually read) you'd see that it starts with `DELIMITER $$`

Comment: Which SQL client are you using?

Comment: Happened in both PHP code and with "emma". I also tried mysql workbench but it doesn't work well in its current version on my Ubuntu 14.10. What does the client have to do with it, anyway?

Comment: I also tried putting them on the same line, so it's not that. Also, if you refer me somewhere else, please also explain the main issue I should be looking for, if it's not the main one.

Comment: well, I just tried not separating the ending delimiter from the END keyword (again) and it still doesn't work.

Comment: `delimiter` is not a SQL statement, it's a command supported by the SQL client (e.g. `mysql`). Of course this will not work with PHP. In a nutshell only statements [listed in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax.html) are "real" SQL statements. Other utility statements depend on the SQL client being used. Some will support `delimiter` some won't (or have other ways of changing the delimiter)